# Average values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to create a new list of values, `my_qty` where each item is equal to the average of all values in `d[key]['qty']` where `d[key]['start date']` matches a value in `my_dates`. I think I am close, but am getting hung up on the nested portion.

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
my_dates = [datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 14, 0, 0)]

d = {
    'ID1' : {'start date': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 12, 0, 0) , 'qty': 12},
    'ID2' : {'start date': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 13, 0, 0) , 'qty': 34},
    'ID3' : {'start date': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 12, 0, 0) , 'qty': 35},
    'ID4' : {'start date': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 11, 0, 0) , 'qty': 40},
}

my_qty = []
for item in my_dates:
  my_qty.append([np.mean(x for x in d[key]['qty']) if d[key]['start date'] == my_dates[item]])

print my_qty
```

Desired Output:

```
[23.5,34,0]
```

To clarify the output per request:

```
[average of d[key]['qty'] where d[key]['start date '] == my_dates[0], average of d[key]['qty'] where d[key]['start date '] == my_dates[1], average of d[key]['qty'] where d[key]['start date '] == my_dates[2],]
```

Comment: Can you clarify regarding desired output?

Comment: @user3467349 added some clarity with half english/half code to OP

Comment: You were pretty close in your approach. My bad about not figuring out what you were trying to do right away. Btw I don't think np.mean gives any speed gains on non-numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one line answer:

```
mean_qty = [np.mean([i['qty'] for i in d.values()\
 if i.get('start date') == day] or 0) for day in my_dates] 

In [12]: mean_qty
Out[12]: [23.5, 34.0, 0.0]
```

The purpose of `or 0` is to return 0 as the OP wanted if there are no `qty` since np.mean on an empty list returns `nan` by default.

If you need speed, then building on jme's excellent second part, you can do this (I cut his time down by 3x by not recalculating the mean until it's called for):

```
class RunningMean(object):
    def __init__(self, total=0.0, n=0):
        self.total=total
        self.n = n

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.total += other
        self.n += 1
        return self

    def mean(self): 
        return (self.total/self.n if self.n else 0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "RunningMean(total=%f, n=%i)" %(self.total, self.n)
means = defaultdict(RunningMean)
for v in d.values():
    means[v["start date"]] += (v["qty"])

Out[351]: 
[RunningMean(mean= 40.000000),
 RunningMean(mean= 34.000000),
 RunningMean(mean= 23.500000)]
```

Comment: The `lambda` is completely unnecessary (as is the backslash at the end of the first line). You can use `[np.mean([i['qty'] for i in d.values() if i.get('start date') == day] or 0) for day in my_dates]` instead (with any number of line breaks within the brackets). You might also want to explain the `or 0` bit, which has a non-obvious purpose.

Comment: Backslash is so you don't have to scroll to see all the code.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the backslash to break the line. Try taking the backslash out (leave the newline). It will work, since the line break is inside of the brackets for the list comprehension. You can also break lines inside of parentheses, so tuple literals, function calls (and declarations) can all be wrapped easily.

Comment: @user3467349: one line answer is really get, where to get concept clear about such one line nested condition?

Comment: I'm glad you liked my one-pass method :). A couple suggestions: if you want to overload an operator, overload `__iadd__` rather than `__add__`, since the former's semantics are in-place addition, while the latter does not (in general) modify the operands. Your `__repr__` should if at all possible return a string that is valid python code for creating your object. If you'd like to only compute the mean when asked for, I'd make it a property. Lastly, keeping the running mean as you have *is* slightly faster, though not by 3x (my tests show 1.15 times).

Comment: @jme Thanks, I know I shouldn't have overloaded `__add__` like that, it was late at at night =/ recalculating the mean every time will get more expensive with larger datasets -

Answer (score 6):

## With pure python

The simple way is to group the quantities by date into a dictionary:

```
import collections

quantities = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [])

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    quantities[v["start date"]].append(v["qty"])
```

Then run over that dictionary to compute the means:

```
means = {k: float(sum(q))/len(q) for k,q in quantities.iteritems()}
```

Giving:

```
>>> means
{datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 11, 0, 0): 40.0,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 12, 0, 0): 23.5,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 13, 0, 0): 34.0}
```

If you wanted to be clever, it's possible to compute the mean in a single pass by keeping the current mean and the tally of the number of values you've seen. You can even abstract this in a class:

```
class RunningMean(object):
    def __init__(self, mean=None, n=0):
        self.mean = mean
        self.n = n

    def insert(self, other):
        if self.mean is None:
            self.mean = 0.0
        self.mean = (self.mean * self.n + other) / (self.n + 1)
        self.n += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        args = (self.__class__.__name__, self.mean, self.n)
        return "{}(mean={}, n={})".format(*args)
```

And one pass through your data will give you your answer:

```
import collections
means = collections.defaultdict(lambda: RunningMean())
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    means[v["start date"]].insert(v["qty"])
```

## With pandas

The *really* simple way is to use the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) library, as it was made for things like this. Here's some code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
means = df.groupby("start date").aggregate(np.mean)
```

Giving:

```
>>> means
             qty
start date      
2014-10-11  40.0
2014-10-12  23.5
2014-10-13  34.0
```

Comment: I like the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some working code which should help you:

```
for item in my_dates:
  nums = [ d[key]['qty'] for key in d if d[key]['start date'] == item ]
  if len(nums):
    avg = np.mean(nums)
  else:
    avg = 0
  print item, nums, avg
```

Note that `np.mean` doesn't work on an empty list, so you have to check the length of the numbers you want to average.

Comment: you don't need len(nums) just do np.mean(nums or 0)